# how to verify that form data is submitted node js

Tags: node.js, request, forms-authentication

i am using `nodejs request module`to login . but the user is not authenticated after the request. i am trying this code

```
var request = require('request');
request.post({
     rejactUnauthorized: false,
    headers: {'content-type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    url:     'https://site.com/default.aspx',
    body:    "UserName=myusername&Password=mypassword"
}, function(err, res, body){
    console.log(body);
});
```

it gives me status 200 but it renders the default page its not navigating to the next page.
can anyone guide me where is the problem?

my login form is on the default.aspx

THANKS

Comment: What is "rejactUnauthorized: false"? Have you tried using form instead of header/body combo?

Comment: thanks for response...it is for ssl certificate error. the site i am trying to access gives the error: "unable_to_verify_leaf_signature"... when i used this it is solved. i tried using form but have no luck yet...